# Using quasar flex classes to achieve a centered sidebar menu while maintaining logo at the top

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, quasar-framework

Is it possible using quasar flex classes to achieve the logo class in the top of the sidebar menu while then centering the parent div with class name menu-icons until the screen is collapsed vertically and then just sitting above the logo without squishing it or overlapping. Basically centering until the space between the centered menu and the logo becomes zero in which case it then just stacks.

My sidebar code as follows is :

```
<template>
  <div style="height: calc(100vh - 64px); overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="window-height bg-black text-white text-center">
      <div class="q-pt-xl logo">
        <q-img
          src="~assets/img/sidebarLogo.png"
          spinner-color="white"
          style="max-width: 45%;"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="menu-icons">
        <div class="q-py-lg">
          <q-list class="curved-parent-ul">
            <q-item v-for="(menuItem, index) in primaryMenuArr" :key="index" class="curved-child-li"
              :active="activeMenuItem === menuItem.name"
              @click="activeMenuItem = menuItem.name"
              active-class="active"
              clickable
              manual-focus
              :link="menuItem.link"
              no-ripple>
              <q-icon size="sm" :name="menuItem.icon" class="absolute-center" />
            </q-item>
          </q-list>
        </div>
        <q-separator dark inset :size="'1.5px'" class="bg-white"/>
        <div class="q-py-lg">
          <q-list class="curved-parent-ul">
            <q-item v-for="(menuItem, index) in secondaryMenuArr" :key="index" class="curved-child-li"
              :active="activeMenuItem === menuItem.name"
              @click="activeMenuItem = menuItem.name"
              active-class="active"
              clickable
              manual-focus
              no-ripple>
              <q-icon size="sm" :name="menuItem.icon" class="absolute-center" />
            </q-item>
          </q-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
  import {useLayoutStore} from '../stores/layout-store'

  const layoutStore = useLayoutStore()
  const {primaryNavigationDrawer} = storeToRefs(layoutStore)
  const leftDrawerOpen: Ref<boolean> = ref(true)
  const activeMenuItem: Ref<string> = ref('Home')

  interface menuArr {
    name: string;
    ariaLabel: string;
    icon: string;
    link: string;
    }
  const primaryMenuArr: menuArr[ ] = [
    { name: 'Home', ariaLabel: 'Home', icon: 's_dashboard', link: '#' },
    { name: 'Stuff', ariaLabel: 'Stuff', icon: 's_drive_folder_upload', link: '#' },
    { name: 'Stuff 2', ariaLabel: 'Stuff 2', icon: 's_work', link: '#' },
    ]

  const secondaryMenuArr: menuArr[ ] = [
    { name: 'Settings', ariaLabel: 'Settings', icon: 's_settings', link: '#' },
    { name: 'Log Off', ariaLabel: 'Upload', icon: 's_logout', link: '#' },
    ]
</script>
<style scoped>
.curved-parent-ul {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0s;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;

}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:-30px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 #fff;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 15px -15px 0 #fff;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
</style>
```